# Marmalade SDK Simulator error: Couldn't initialize Direct Draw

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, emulation, marmalade

I have been working with marmalade for some weeks. But since today my simulator is not working anymore. I always get "error: Couldn't initialize Direct Draw" when i launch the simulator.
I tried uninstalling marmalade and restarting pc but nothing is helping.

Anyone has an idea what this can be, or things I can try?

Error message can be seen:

[image: here]

PC specs if this might help: 
- Acer Aspire notebook 
- Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64bit
- Intel i5 2410M
- 6GB RAM
- AMD HD 6650M 1GB

Comment: Did you do any driver updates? Try reverting back to an old video driver? Also did you make any changes in your code or is it literally just from the simulator?

Comment: Did not do any driver updates. Its the simulator crashing, nothing to do with my code. Tried some examples from marmalade and they also crash with same error.

Comment: I tried installing latest drivers. Still the same.

Comment: Since its a DirectDraw error try changing the graphics setting in the simulator to using something else. I don't remember all of the options but there are a lot.  Make sure you are using SW mode.  If none of this works then try looking around marmalades website.  They have a pretty helpful community.

Comment: I can not change graphics settings in simulator, because when i start the simulator it gives the error only option is to close it. Using SW mode did not change a thing. I already posted and looked around marmalade forum. An admin has responded to my problem but no fix found yet. Can check the post here: http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/7644

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may come across this, the same thing happened to me just yesterday. I started getting the "Couldn't initialize Direct Draw" on startup after having made a few changes under `Preferences -> Display`.

I fixed it by going to `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Marmalade\` and deleting (or renaming) the `preferences.icf` file.  This isn't removed after an uninstall, so if you find yourself in this situation, this seems to be the only way to reset everything.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try.

First, try running your program from inside Visual C++ by **pressing and holding** F5.  This will cause the simulator to start but won't start executing your program, which might then give you a chance to change the settings in the simulator.

Failing that, if you look in the data directory you should find a file called development.icf which is the current simulator settings.  Try deleting this and running again which will cause the simulator to revert to its default settings.

Comment: You mean development in my project folder? I deleted that one did not change a thing.